# Can you use the new Azure Service Bus Library with the previous one?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The new service bus library Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus uses the ServiceBusReceivedMessage for a received message

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceivedmessage?view=azure-dotnet

The older libraries uses a different message format for service bus triggers being the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet

If I post an old style Message to the service bus, will I be able to retrieve it using the new library and format.

Comment: What's the older library you are using to send the message? Can you please share a sample message that you are sending.

Comment: @GauravMantri added a reference to the older message format?

Answer (score 3):

Client SDKs operate against the same service. What matters is the agreement between the sending and the receiving parties on the message payload and encoding. As long as both parties agree on that, there's no problem sending messages using older SDK and receiving using newer SDK.

You should be careful when sending messages using the oldest SDK, `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`. That SDK used `XmlObjectSerializer` to serialize the body which is not the same as a byte array that is used by the newer SDK `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` and the latest SDK `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`. If you do need to interop with the oldest SDK, there's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample08_Interop.md) to follow.

Comment: The library that is used is the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extension.ServiceBus that depends on Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Comment: The same rules apply. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extension.ServiceBus is using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus as a dependency to receive messages from Service Bus in a Function App. If you update to the latest of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extension.ServiceBus (version 5 and later), you'll be using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.